# Query a website/web service using python

Tags: python, twitter, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to find tweets per day for a twitter handle, i found this site called " http://www.howoftendoyoutweet.com/"- it gives you the tweets per day , when you provide it with the twitter handle. I want my python script to query this website for a list of twitter handles and extract the tweets per day from the page.

I know that i have to use urllib2 and json for it, but not been able to. Is there any better way to find tweets per day?

Comment: What does the current version of your script look like?

Comment: @cms_mgr i have been able to collect the list of handles i want to query,from there i haven't made any progress. So i can say im stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the [python-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) library might give you better results.